# Would it be possible / necessary to prove that a math law can be applied to a given formula. Is intuitive recognition of structure similarity enough?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, logic, foundations

I can apply associativity law to the following formula : [(a+b)+ c] +d

in the following way :

(1) [(a+b)+ c] +d

(2) = (a+b)+ (c +d)

(3) = a + [b+ (c+d)]

I do this so to say intuitively, recognizing intuitively the syntactic structure (A+B) + C in (1) and the structure A+(B+C) in (2).

I say intuitively, for the only reason I could give is that I *see* that the structure is the same.

In the same way, in logic, it seems there is some intuition involved in the fact of substituting

(A&~B)--> ~ ~ ~(A<-->(CvD)

for ~ [ (A&~B) & ~ ~ ~ ~(A<-->(CvD) ]

on the ground that :  ~ [ (A&~B) & ~ ~ ~ ~(A<-->(CvD) ] has the form  :

~ (X & ~Y)

and that ~ (X & ~Y) is equivalent to (X --> Y).

My question is : have mathematicians or logicians  ever required  this structure similarity to be proved ( not just seen) ? would it be possible to get rid of all intuition here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to prove, say, $(a+b)+(c+d) = a+(b+(c+d))$ from the associativity law.

Recall that this law states : "for all $x,y,z$, $(x+y)+z= x+(y+z)$".

Then you just have to say : let $x=a, y=b, z=(c+d)$. Then $(a+b)+(c+d)=(x+y)+z$, by definition, and $a+(b+(c+d)) = x+(y+z)$, again by definition. The associativity law applied to these specific $x,y,z$ (recall that it holds for all $x,y,z$ !) yields the equality of the two terms : $(a+b)+(c+d) = a+(b+(c+d))$.

I did not have to "see intuitively" anything, I just applied a formal rule that I was allowed to apply because I assumed it.

Of course, all this is very straightforward and obvious, that's why people don't bother justifying it when they write mathematics; but for instance if you wanted a computer to check your proof you would have to tell it how you're using the associativity law (of course a lot of computer proof assistants have the ability built in to detect it from just saying "assoc." or something related, but what's happening is that they're saying "oh right, this works because I can just say $x=a, y=b$ and $z=(c+d)$")

Comment: You have to "see intuitively" that a formula is a substitution instance of the law. More generally, you need to be able to "see intuitively" that a rule of inference is applied correctly. Well, the person checking the purported proof does. What stops me from claiming you misapplied associativity or saying "Let $x=a$, $y=b$, $z=(c+d)$, then by associativity $1=0$"? The analogy in the mechanized case is you and I have different implementations of a proof checker which give different results. How do we know which one is the buggy one?

Comment: @DerekElkins : it seems like you're saying that there's no way to check whether a formal proof is correct : I agree, but that's philosophy, and it's on another level than this discussion. Here I'm arguing about something reasonable, but nonetheless it seems to me that this doesn't have anything to do with intuition (although it requires some faith, as all math does : faith that we - human or computer- can, at least in principle, check whether a purported proof follows the agreed upon rules)

Comment: @DerekElkins : or at least I believe the question was not about this sort of "hardcore skepticism", but rather about knowing whether their proof using associativity was formal, and not just intuitive - formal in the agreed upon sense of course

Comment: While I would word it differently, that is what I'm saying. I don't consider it philosophy to address how we check the rules. For example, we usually require proof checking to be computable, and this directly goes to *how* we "see" that a proof is correct. Of course, you can indeed be skeptical about the outcome of an algorithm, and, ultimately, you can get into philosophical arguments. However, the point of formal logic and the theory of computation is a *reduction* in the audacity of our basic claims.

Comment: @DerekElkins : I completely agree, but I would say that checking a substitution of terms for variables in an axiom is not a very audacious claim. If it is, then I don't really see how we could make maths less audacious (but perhaps I'm missing something, I'd be very glad to be mistaken)

Comment: It's not that audacious but it is *more* audacious than looking up small symbols in a small table which is most of what would be required by a Turing machine. Also, substitution into formulas with quantifiers is significantly more complicated than the lackadaisical attitude most mathematicians have toward it suggests. It is regularly misunderstood and a few iterations can quickly produce exponentially large terms. These checks can be quite involved, e.g. in the Calculus of Inductive Constructions it is easy to make checking reflexivity require showing a propositional logic formula is valid.

Comment: @DerekElkins well then perhaps you should write an answer to that effect ! It would be more interesting for OP than reading these comments, and I would probably learn a thing or 2 from it

Answer (score 1):

Formally, when associativity holds in some structure closed under addition, we can simply rename $a+b$ to $x$, and then formally apply the associative law to get from (1) to (2). A similar method will get you from (2) to (3).

Answer (score 1):

In everyday arithmetic you just know this.

In any context where that three term associative law holds you can prove by induction that it doesn't matter where you put the parentheses when adding $n$ terms.